# Modifying the length of different bodyparts in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a [model](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/man/male-character--4) of a human body, I am able to load that in threejs with the obj loader.  Now after loading the model in threejs I need to do some post-processing like

- scaling the length of arm
- scaling the length of leg

Is it possible to do that, how can I do that ? I know that obj file store the necessary information to create meshes(i.e. vertices and faces) moreover material information if required. Can we add any extra information to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and this: https://threejs.org/docs/

Answer (score -1):

You want to rig your model. You need to define the skeleton, and Three.js can then use "bones" to scale, position and stretch aspects of your mesh. A simple example of a rigged model in three.js is here:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/SkinnedMesh

Rigging your model in blender is available as a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEqB-eKcv7k&index=15&list=PLOGomoq5sDLutXOHLlESKG2j9CCnCwVqg